# How to check monthly transferred In and transferred Out in c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get the monthly transferred In data by **BCode** and monthly transferred out data in the table. We can identify that the company transferred to another category by **BCode** when **BCode** change that means the company has transferred to that category.

I want to get the transferred in and transferred out where BCode = 1

**Table**

```
 | Id        Refno         TransactionDate       BCode     ReceiptDate             Total
 +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | 70488974 K0702694    2014-01-01 00:00:00.000     1   2014-04-01 00:00:00.000   -1429,72 |
 | 72107868 K0731218    2014-01-01 00:00:00.000     1   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000   -4052,65 |
 | 70173504 K0770815    2014-01-01 00:00:00.000     23  2014-01-01 00:00:00.000   -706,46  |
 | 70578306 K0773716    2014-01-01 00:00:00.000     99  2014-01-01 00:00:00.000   -443,45  |
 | 70245176 K0702694    2014-02-01 00:00:00.000     1   2014-02-01 00:00:00.000   -1298,23 |
 | 72225353 K0731218    2014-02-01 00:00:00.000     1   2015-02-01 00:00:00.000   -987,44  |
 | 70942793 K0773716    2014-02-01 00:00:00.000     1   2014-05-01 00:00:00.000   -443,45  |
 | 70947050 K0770815    2014-02-01 00:00:00.000     1   2014-05-01 00:00:00.000   270,26   |
 | 70370825 K0702694    2014-03-01 00:00:00.000     1   2014-03-01 00:00:00.000   -1323,78 |
 | 70298756 K0770815    2014-03-01 00:00:00.000     23  2014-02-01 00:00:00.000   -697,49  |
 | 70578306 K0773716    2014-03-01 00:00:00.000     99  2014-04-01 00:00:00.000   -443,45  |
 | 71564379 K0731218    2014-03-01 00:00:00.000     13  2014-09-01 00:00:00.000   -2236,26 |
```

The output is supposed to be like this:

**Monthly Transferred In** (From 01/02/2014 )

```
| Refno      From BCode   Total |
+-------------------------------+
| K0770815    23        270,26  |
| K0773716    99       -443,45  |
+-------------------------------+
```

**Monthly Transferred Out** (From 01/02/2014 )

```
| Refno      To BCode   Total |
+-------------------------------+
| K0770815    23        270,26  |
| K0773716    99        -443,45 |
| K0731218   13        -2236,26 |
+-------------------------------+
```

**My current code looks like this**

```
public DataSet _getMTIO(DateTime startMonth, long bCode)
{
    var query_in = (from _in in _entities.Transactions
                    join _bcode in _entities.BCodes on _in.BCode equals _seta.SetaCode
                    where (_in.TransactionDate >= startMonth 
                    || startMonth == DateTime.MinValue)
                    && (_in.BCode == bCode || bCode < 0)
                    && !_entities.Transactions.Where(y => y.TransactionDate < startMonth)
                    .Select(y => y.Refno).Contains(_in.Refno)
                     select new
                     {
                         RefNo = _in.Refno,
                         FromBCode= _in.BCode,
                         Total = _in.Total
                     });

      var query_out = (from _out in _entities.LevyTransactions
                       join _bcode in _entities.BCodes on _in.BCode equals _seta.SetaCode
                       where (_in.TransactionDate >= startMonth 
                       || startMonth == DateTime.MinValue)
                       && (_out.BCode == bCode || bCode < 0)
                       && !_entities.Transactions.Where(y => y.TransactionDate > startMonth)
                       .Select(y => y.BCode).Contains(_out.BCode)
                       select new
                       {
                           RefNo = _out.Refno,
                           ToBCode= _out.BCode,
                           Total = _out.Total_out.Total
                       });
 }
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Yes I have tried but it not giving me what I want let update my question to add my current code.

Comment: @Dlamini.M can you explain better how you get the results? From your description it's not very clear.

Comment: Why in your examples you have selected records with BCode 23, 99 and 13 and you mention that search with BCode = 1? Why 270,26 has BCode = 23 when in sample data has 1? Explain better what you want to achive.

Comment: @Klaudiuszbryjamus Remember I am checking transferred in and transferred out only. So as you see BCode=1. I am checking records that has moved into BCode 1 and moved out from BCode . I hope you see in the column name in the output for **transferred In** is called FromBCode  I am showing which BCode record is coming from and **transferred Out** is called ToBCode I am showing where the record goes to.

Comment: @Dlamini.M sorry, but your explanation is not enough clear

Comment: As an aside, you should look up the correct naming conventions for C#.  Your method and variable naming is not inline with the recommended approach.  Also you should name methods correctly.  Code is generally write once, read often.  Whilst _getMTIO may mean something to you now, it may not be clear to anybody else reading this.

Comment: @Dlamini.M How do you check TransactionDate? Is it specific one month - e.g. check which of transactions change from BCode 1 to something else in march 2014 (so I will search all 1's before march 2014 and match them to all non 1's in march 2014 and than the same for april)? Explain this.